# Render html and load its css/js files without using static files from Django

Tags: javascript, css, django

I am trying to render a html using a local directory but I keep getting the error: The resource from "/path/to/js/" was blocked due to MIME type ("text/html") mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff)". I believe I am getting this error because I am not using the staticfiles that django says to use. But that is exactly what I want to not do. Basically, I have an app that exports presentation slides in HTML format, but it puts the js files and css files in its own directory which has a completely different structure than Django's staticfiles. I wanted to know if there was a way I could render the page and get its js/css to make it work. I was able to get the html from the other directory but that's where it stops and gives me an error.

Thanks.

Comment: "_but it puts the js files and css files in its own directory which has a completely different structure than Django's staticfiles_" and what stops you from using this directory as the static file directory? Django doesn't put any restriction on how your static file directory is structured. You only need to point it to a directory so your statement really doesn't make any sense...

Comment: See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/#configuring-static-files specifically the part about the setting `STATICFILES_DIRS`

Comment: If I did add it to Django's staticfiles directory, I would have to collectstatic everytime I add a new html presentation slide, no?